# is_page() not working in functions.php file

Tags: php, wordpress

I have the following code in my functions.php file yet when i go to then page /previous-editions the code does not execute..

```
if ( is_page('previous-editions') ) {
    $test = 'test';
    var_dump($test);
}
```

I've also tried:

```
if ( is_page( array( 'previous-editions', 'newsletter', 'minutes-of-agms' , 'club-accounts' , 'club-rules' , 'gdpr-policy' ) ) ) {
    http_response_code(404);
    die();
}
```

And still nothing is working, I've also tried checking the page ID and that also doesn't work.

Comment: It doesn't execute, as in, it won't run at all or it's giving unexpected results?

Comment: because your functions.php file is loaded earlier then page.php

Comment: So good practice is made a function in functions.php file and use this function in your page.php file or any other custom page files

Comment: You can check & try from below link:
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/138473/if-is-pagepage-id-not-working/251528#251528

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've loaded the function on the template redirection action and it seems to have remedied the issue.

```
function accessDenied(){
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $userID = get_current_user_id();
        if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $userID, 'member' ) ) {

        } else {
            if ( is_page( array( 'previous-editions', 'newsletter', 'minutes-of-agms' , 'club-accounts' , 'club-rules' , 'gdpr-policy' ) ) ) {
                http_response_code(404);
                die();
            }
        }
    } else {
        global $post;
        $pageID = $post->ID;

        if ($pageID == 1157 || $pageID == 1161 || $pageID == 1164 || $pageID == 1165 || $pageID == 2191 || $pageID == 2195 || $pageID == 3739 || $pageID == 1159 ) {
            http_response_code(404);
            require get_404_template();
            die();
        }
    }
} add_action( 'template_redirect', 'accessDenied' );?>
```

I then extended this to work with a multi selected Page Object field in Advanced Custom Fields so that I didn't need to add each page manually in the code and redirected the page not to a 404 but a page that explained they need the membership.

```
function accessDenied(){
    $restricedContent = get_field('restricted_pages','options');

    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
        $userID = get_current_user_id();
        if ( wc_memberships_is_user_active_member( $userID, 'conway-club-member' ) ) {

        } else {
            if ( is_page( $restricedContent ) ) {
                wp_redirect( get_permalink( 4105 ) );
                die;
            }
        }
    } else {
        if ( is_page( $restricedContent ) ) {
            wp_redirect( get_permalink( 4105 ) );
            die;
        }
    }
} add_action( 'template_redirect', 'accessDenied' );
```

Comment: Nice work! `template_redirect` is 100% the correct way to go about this. Not necessary, but just a thought to make it more readable -- maybe assign all of the `$pageID` `OR` conditional values to an array and check via `in_array()` instead. So `if ( in_array( $post->ID, $page_ids ) ) { // your action here }` -- again not necessary, just a suggestion :)

Comment: @TyBailey i actually extended out it use an advanced custom fields page object so it was easy to add pages to the list of 404 pages :)

Answer (score 0):

functions.php is processed way before you can know which page is being loaded. Instead of assigning value to variable put your code into function and use that function in page.php template.

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me:

```
add_action( 'wp', 'set_404' );
function set_404() {
    if ( is_page( [ 'page-slug', 'page-slug-2'] ) {
        global $wp_query;
        $wp_query->set_404();
        status_header(404);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if(get_the_ID() == 123)
{
  // code
}
```

123 is your page ID

Comment: Not working either